# I need help writing a complex SELECT statement

Tags: sql

i am trying to write an sql statement that will select items from one table and order it by the result of the other table..

the 2 tables are:

**events:**
id, name

**attendance:**
user, event

ive got this statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `attendance` 
WHERE event='1' 
  AND user IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,444,153)
```

I am using this to get the number of friends that coming to event number 1.

**now I want to combine that statement with another one to create a statement that select all the events, and order it by the number of friends that going...
how can i write that statement?**

Thank you very much, Amir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendance att WHERE att.event = ev.id) AS attending
FROM
    event ev
ORDER BY
    attending DESC
```

However, although I *would* try something like that, fact is I *haven't*, so this might not work as is.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a join like:

```
SELECT events.id, COUNT(attendance.user) AS attending
FROM attendance INNER JOIN events ON attendance.event = events.id
WHERE (attendance.user IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,444,153))
GROUP BY events.id
ORDER BY attending DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the list of numbers is the set of friends you're interested in (it would be better to store them in a table - that's how you record information in a database), then:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, COUNT(*) AS friends
  FROM attendance AS a
  JOIN event      AS e ON a.event = e.id
 WHERE a.user IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,444,153)
 GROUP BY e.id, e.name;
```

Complexity, of course, is in the eye of the beholder - this is not actually complex.  Note that as written, it does not list events to which none of the friends go.  If you want that, you need a LEFT OUTER JOIN and you need the 'friend filter' earlier than the main WHERE clause:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, COUNT(user) AS friends
  FROM event AS e
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT user, event
          FROM attendance
         WHERE user IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,444,153)
       ) AS a
    ON a.event = e.id
 GROUP BY e.id, e.name;
```

The COUNT(user) aggregate returns zero if all the rows in a group contain NULL in the user column.

Untested SQL.

Comment: Also working very good, but im not sure about the efficiency i need to fill the table in order to test it... thank you!

Comment: @Amir: remember that correctness matters first; only when something is correct does efficiency come into play.  Also, if the set of friends were in a table, you'd have a third join, and you might find that the optimizer works better with the table than the IN.  Increase the number of friends from 15 to 75, and you might well find that the table outperforms the IN.  (Way back - 1990 or so - I had to write an adaptive query generator because for small sets of values in the IN clause, the IN notation was best, but for large sets, it was better to store the set in a (temporary) table and join it!)

Comment: Well can u tell me how to make it with temporary table and join it? because I only found IN method to do that... thank you

Comment: @Amir: I can't tell you how to create a temporary table in your DBMS because you have not told me which DBMS you use.  And you can read the manuals as well as I can.

Comment: @Amir: I strongly hinted that you should RTFM and not ask silly follow-up questions (see [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html); the relevant FM is [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html). However, in the long term, you probably are going to change the list of friends, or create more groups of friends. Then you'll need a regular table identifying sets of friends. It is easier to change data in tables than to find all the places where you've encoded lists of numbers into SQL statements.

Comment: Ok thanks. about the friends table, i am using facebook connect so i get the friend list from FACEBOOK API QUERY... thats why im not using tables...